# Weird situation about Zyxel modem

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem, dsl-modem

I have a zyxel p660hn-t1 modem that is about 3-4 years old. It was working properly.
Now even it is connected to power outlet, power led is not lighting whereas DSL and WLAN leds are lighting constantly. Other leds are also not lighting.

I tried resetting but it didn't work. Any ideas other than buying new modem?

Thank you.

Comment: Try replacing the power adapter.

Comment: how can a power adapter lead to such thing?

Comment: It might not provide the amperage that the modem needs anymore. I've seen similar situations before...

Comment: Try another adapter of same voltage, at least that amperage and correct polarity.